# JQuery validate plugin errorPlacement passes in an error object when a string is expected

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm having a similar problem.  Shouldn't "error" be an error string?  When I alert the error it is an object([object Object].  When I take out the "errorPlacement" block it works fine.  I tried putting the errorPlacement block at the end, too.  When I change line 6 like this:
element.closest("div").append("test message");
I DO GET "test message" string in the form without error.  So the problem is that "error" is an object rather than a string.  Is this a problem with the plugin?
I am using jQuery validation plug-in 1.7 and jquery 1.6ish

```
$("#student-set-form").validate({
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {                
            console.log(error);
            alert(error);
            element.closest("div").append(error);
        },
        rules: {
            NAME: {
                required: true
            },
            LOCATION: {
                required: true
            },
            DESC: {
            },
            MIN_GPA: {
                required: function() {
                    return $("input[name='MAX_GPA']").val() != ''; // yes, min references max
                },
                range: [0, 4]
            },
            MAX_GPA: {
                required: function() {
                    return $("input[name='MIN_GPA']").val() != ''; // yes, max references min   
                },
                range: [0, 4]
            },
            MIN_CR_HOURS_COMPLETE: {
                required: function() {
                    return $("input[name='MAX_CR_HOURS_COMPLETE']").val() != ''; // yes, min references max  
                },
                range: [0, 200]
            },
            MAX_CR_HOURS_COMPLETE: {
                required: function() {
                    return $("input[name='MIN_CR_HOURS_COMPLETE']").val() != ''; // yes, max references min           
                },
                range: [0, 200]
            },
            MIN_LASTNAME_INITIAL: {
                required: function() {
                    return $("input[name='MAX_LASTNAME_INITIAL']").val() != ''; // yes, max references min           
                },
            },
            MAX_LASTNAME_INITIAL: {
                required: function() {
                    return $("input[name='MIN_LASTNAME_INITIAL']").val() != ''; // yes, max references min           
                },
            },
            DAYS_VISIBLE: {
                required: true,
                range: [1, 365]
            },
            DAYS_BEFORE_VISIBLE: {
                required: true,
                range: [1, 3]
            },
            APPOINTMENT_LEGNTH_MINUTES: {
                required: true,
                range: [1, 40320]
            },
            NUM_STUDENTS: {
                required: true,
                range: [1, 10000]
            }

        },
        messages: {
            NAME: {
                required: "Please enter a name."
            },
            LOCATION: {
                required: "Please enter a location."
            },
            DESC: {
            },
            MIN_GPA: {
                required: "Min/Max GPA are optional, but if one is set, the other must also be set.",
                range: "Min GPA must be between 0 and 4.0"
            },
            MAX_GPA: {
                required: "Min/Max GPA are optional, but if one is set, the other must also be set.",
                range: "Man GPA must be between 0 and 4.0"
            },
            MIN_CR_HOURS_COMPLETE: {
                required: "Min/Max Credit hours are optional, but if one is set, the other must also be set.",
                range: "Min GPA must be between 0 and 4.0"
            },
            MAX_CR_HOURS_COMPLETE: {
                required: "Min/Max Credit hours are optional, but if one is set, the other must also be set.",
                range: "Max Cr Hrs must be between 0 and 200."
            },
            MIN_LASTNAME_INITIAL: {
                required: "Min/Max Last Initials are optional, but if one is set, the other must also be set."
            },
            MAX_LASTNAME_INITIAL: {
                required: "Min/Max Last Initials are optional, but if one is set, the other must also be set."
            },
            DAYS_VISIBLE: {
                required: "Number days prior visible is required.",
                range: "Number days prior visible must be between 1 and 365 days."
            },
            DAYS_BEFORE_VISIBLE: {
                required: "# weekdays hide before appt is required.",
                range: "# weekdays hide before appt must be be between 1, 2, or 3 days."
            },
            APPOINTMENT_LEGNTH_MINUTES: {
                required: "Appointment Length in minutes is required.",
                range: "Appointment Length in minutes must be beween 1 and 1000 minutes."
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yes, `error` is supposed to be an object.  Now what's the problem and what are you really trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

Quote OP:

> "Shouldn't "error" be an error string? When I alert the error it is an
>   object([object Object]."

No, it should not be a string.  It is indeed an object which looks something like this...

```
<label for="myfield" class="error">This field is required</label>
```

If you want to extract the string from the `error` object, use the [jQuery `.text()` method](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

This will give you a string containing the error message:

```
error.text()
```

Otherwise, it's not clear what problem you're having with your code.